# XPages Extension Library: namepicker not working

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Is there any issue with namepicker of Extension Library version 9.0.0.v00_01_20130415-0518?
It does not display popup window for address book, here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:panel>
            <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djName">
                <xe:this.dataProvider>
                    <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookDb="names.nsf" addressBookSel="all">
                    </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
                </xe:this.dataProvider>
            </xe:namePicker>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
            <xe:djextNameTextBox id="djName" multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true">
            </xe:djextNameTextBox>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

And also, I have manager's rights on names.nsf database.

Edit:
strange behavior! I change `<xe:djextNameTextBox` control to `<xp:inputText` and its works fine. How to debug `xe:djextNameTextBox` control to figure out the problem?

Edit 2:
Following error display when xsp page load:

> Uncaught Error: Could not load 'dijit.form._FormValueWidget'; last tried '../dijit/form/_FormValueWidget.js' dojo.js:14
>   dojo._loadModule.dojo.require dojo.js:14
>   (anonymous function) @Fi&@Ez&@EOf&@Ek.js:107
>
> Uncaught Error: Could not load class 'extlib.dijit.NameTextBox @Fi&@Ez&@EOf&@Ek.js:20
>   (anonymous function) @Fi&@Ez&@EOf&@Ek.js:20

```
$DBrH_ dojo.js:14
$DBpd_ @Fi&@Ez&@EOf&@Ek.js:20
$DBpe_ @Fi&@Ez&@EOf&@Ek.js:20
_4c @Fi&@Ez&@EOf&@Ek.js:20
dojo.loaded dojo.js:14
dojo._callLoaded dojo.js:14
dojo._modulesLoaded dojo.js:14
dojo._loadInit
```

After page load, when I click on name picker button another error display:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'selectValue'

Comment: strange behavior! I change <xe:djextNameTextBox control  to <xp:inputText and its works fine. How to debug xe:djextNameTextBox control to figure out the problem?

Comment: Please add this comment to your question.

Comment: Check if there is ant error shown in the browser or server console?

Comment: I add error in my question, please let me know how to over come this problem. I also test this xe:djextNameTextBox control on my another server with same configuration (lotus Domino 8.5.3 and Extension Library version 9.0.0.v00_01_20130415-0518), same result here.

Answer (score 1):

Your xe:djextNameTextBox control is not bound to a value. Try binding to e.g. a viewScope variable or a field on a document datasource:

```
<xe:djextNameTextBox id="djName" value="#{viewScope.nameField}" multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true">
</xe:djextNameTextBox>
```

Comment: I try to bind the value with xe:djextNameTextBox but no luck. And without binding value to xp:inputText control it's works.

Answer (score 1):

Notes/Domino 9 now comes with Extension Library built in as standard. You do not need to install the extlib from OpenNTF.

I tested your source code in a default install of Notes 9. I get the following output:

[image]

Clicking the icon gets me this (I added the Admin + clicked OK).

[image]

The output of the page is now this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Simon.... but it should work on version 8.5.3 with latest openntf ext lib.

Comment: This might be a question better asked on OpenNTF then.

Comment: Yes, I already submit that issue to openNTF on 1 July.... still waiting for reply from there!!!

Answer (score 0):

My observation are below:
I uninstall Extension Library version 9.0.0.v00_01_20130415-0518 and upgrade to 900v00_02.20130515-2200, but the problem did not resolved. Then I install 8.5.3.20130315-0724 after uninstalling version 900v00_02.20130515-2200 and it works.

One more thing is that, at first after installing version 8.5.3.20130315-0724 it did not work in chrome browser (which was already opened on my laptop) then I open firefox and surprisingly it shows the address book, I mean that xe:djextNameTextBox control works with name picker control as expected. Then I switch to Chrome and clear all the history and reload the page .....!!! yes its work here too.

I repeat all the above stuff for Extension Library version 9.0.0.v00_01_20130415-0518 and Extension Library version 9.0.0.v00_01_20130415-2200 but xe:djextNameTextBox control not working with that versions.

-mak

Comment: Ashfaq, the 9.0x versions of the extlib are designed for Notes 9, not 8.5.x Can't mix them